# matching service names in docker-compose and those of kubenetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have a configuration in Google Cloud kubernetes that I would like to emulate with docker-compose for local development. My problem is that docker-compose creates a service name with the name of the folder (purplecloud) plus underscore at the front and underscore plus "1" at the end while kubernetes does not. Further, kubenetes does not let me use service names with "_".  This causes me the extra step of modifying my nginx config that routes to this micro-service and other microservices with the same naming problem.

Is there a way to name the service in docker-compose to be same as kubernetes?

My Google Cloud yaml includes

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: account-service # matches name in nginx.conf for rule "location /account/" ie  http://account-service:80/
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort 
  selector:
    app: account-pod
```

I have a nginx pod that needs to route to the above account micro-service.  Nginx can route to this service using

> http://account-service:80/

My docker-compose yaml includes

```
version: '3.1' # must specify or else version 1 will be used

services: 

  account: # DNS name is http://purplecloud_account_1:80/;
    build: 
        context: ./account
        dockerfile: account.Dockerfile
    image: account_get_jwt
    ports:
      - '4001:80' 
      - '42126:42126' # chrome debuger
    environment:
      - PORT=80
```

I have a nginx pod that needs to route to the above account micro-service.  Nginx can route to this service using

> http://purplecloud_account_1:80/

So I need to swap out the nginx config when I go between docker-compose and kubernetes.  Is there a way to change the name of the service in docker-compose to be same as kubernetes?

Comment: Did you look at using minikube for local development? With minikube you can use the same cluster resource files (modulo some templating) as your target environment. docker-compose is a good tool, but there are myriad of subtle differences between it and k8s, can lead to doing the same work twice, or solving interoperability problems like the above. It is unfortunate incidental rather than necessary complexity.

Comment: Minikube totally crashed my windows PC.  Needed to reinstall the OS.  So it scared me away for a while.  Secondly, open a port in docker-compose for a debugger is easy.  Not sure how to do that in kubernetes.

Comment: Sure- the thing is that msft is all-in on kubernetes, both for dev and for prod. There are a ton of kubernetes people working for msft now, working on a number of projects, including dev-time stuff like Draft. I have to imagine a best practices for minikube on win exists, though it might well be tricky. Regarding opening a port, an app debug port is just a service definition, pointed to the app pods, like any other.